# Oracle Service Bus (OSB) Proxy Service Endpoint URI change

Tags: jms, osb

We have an OSB Proxy Service which is currently setup to receive messages from an external jms queue endpoint URI. We have been tasked with creating a JMS bridge over which to receive external messages.

To this end, we have created a bridge with local jms in/out queues and proceeded to edit the OSB Proxy Service's Endpoint URI from that of the old external jms queue to that of our new local bridge's jms queue. However, when we try to activate the changes, we get: `Exception in AppMerge flows' progression` message.

Being quite new to all things OSB, I am unsure as to what this error means and whether re-pointing a Proxy Service's Endpoint URI from remote jms queue to local bridge's jms queue is enough for what we are attempting to do.

Any thoughts on this matter would be much appreciated!

Our OSB version is 10gR3.

Regards,
PM.

Comment: Having looked at the Weblogic server's logs, I can see the following error: `weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: [J2EE:160106]ERROR: The source file, '/server/domain/sbgen/ProxyService_ABC_businesslogic_ou467040.ear', could not be found.`. Trying to find out what this means now...

Comment: As it turns out, the Exception was not due to the attempt to change the Proxy Service's Endpoint URI. The problem was in trying to clear the Proxy Service's associated Service account. And to get around this, we had to first clone the Proxy Service and then change the Endpoint URI and clear the associated Service Account of the newly cloned Proxy Service. And thereafter disabled the original Proxy Service which got replaced by the newly cloned one. Put it down to bug in OSB?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Proxy is not deployed correctly. I think after creating the bridge and queues, restart your server and then try to work.

Comment: thanks for your reply but we had already re-started the server several times. See my comment above to see how we got round the problem in the end! Regards, PM.

Comment: I think you have resolved the issue. I think it should be reported as Bug and should wait for response from Oracle. Please let us know what they report back to you.